# Programatically Evaluate Formula Field Expression

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field

**My objective:**
I want to be able to programatically evaluate a formula expression in the same manner as SFDC does for formula fields.  I wish to do this so that I can have formula parsing which is in line with SFDC standards.

**Example Scenario**
I have an object type MyObject__c with field MyFormula__c.  This field is a String (Text).

For one instance of this object, MyFormula__c = "1+1" (or a more complex scenario - "TotalCost__c - Discount__c")

I want a way that I can take this stored value of a formula, and that I can calculate it wrt my current instance of the object type.  I want to do this at Apex runtime, not at SOQL-data retrieval.  Can anyone help me with this?  Is this even possible?

I've found a number of ways to tackle similar cases: Get a formula field's description at runtime, eval() via ToolingAPI / exception. etc...

I've found options like... Create an instance of the object in memory.  Save it, then query it right back to get its calculated data.  But nothing for calculating in Apex runtime.

**Note** I can create my own formula parser.  I prefer not to in order to maintain standards and streamline UX / etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are so lucky. This has just been added to the Winter '16 release.

```
someSObject.recalculateFormulas();
```

Will do the trick.

> Recalculates all formula fields on an sObject, and sets updated field
>   values. Rather than inserting or updating objects each time you want
>   to test changes to your formula logic, call this method and inspect
>   your new field values. Then make further logic changes as needed.

See http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm

Comment: Oh wow!  This is amazing news! ..... I'm certain I read "without a database commit" somewhere.  But I can't find it now.  Can you confirm that there will be no database commit "under the hood"?  (ie. I will be able to make a callout after using this?)

Comment: I've run some testcode and indeed, there is no DML statements, so you should be good to do callouts.